# Nuget pack how to set/change dependency version via command line

Tags: dependencies, set, nuget, version, pack

The problem how to dynamically change dependency version in the `nuspec` file during `nuget pack`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPacked.Name</id>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <authors>Pawel Cioch</authors>
    <owners>Pawel Cioch</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Some Cool package</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial Release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <tags>replace dependency version</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="dep1" version="I want version here to be same as package version" />
      <dependency id="dep2" version="2.1.3" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

*Please don't ask "why do you need it"*

*Also im sorry if the question is obscure, but since I solved it via try/fail everything seems to be obvious now so "I don't know how to ask"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<version>` tag can be changed simply by using the -Version switch:

```
nuget pack -Version 2.0.0
```

You can also use [Replacement Tokens](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#replacement-tokens). What we can do is use a custom token/tag like this:

```xml
    ...
    <version>$myVersion$</version>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="dep1" version="$myVersion$" />
```

Now to replace this token the -Version switch would not do. We must use the -Properties switch instead:

```
nuget pack -Prop myVersion=3.0.0
```

Here's a more an example of a advanced command:

```
nuget pack My.ProjName\My.ProjName.csproj -Build -Prop Configuration=Release;myVersion=3.0.0 -OutputDirectory SomeDirHere
```

And to play nicely with powershell (for example), you must wrap -Prop value in double quotes if using semicolon for multiple properties

```
$userVersion = Read-Host 'Enter a valid version you want to use'
nuget pack .\My.ProjName\My.ProjName.csproj -Build -Prop "Configuration=Release;myVersion=$userVersion" -OutputDirectory SomeDirHere
```

NOTE: using Nuget's predefined `$version$` token can work but the version in that case would be obtained from **AssemblyInfo.cs** whereas the idea above was to set the version explicitly via the command line.

I hope someone will find it useful and time saving.

Comment: They really should state explicitly that the semicolon separated properties list should be enclosed in quotes, this really threw me.  Thank you.